# Unable to evaluate + remediate CIS level 1 server benchmarks using a custom OpenSCAP profile on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I installed all OpenSCAP packages on RHEL 9.2 VM and then remotely evaluated & remediated the CIS level 1 Server profile benchmarks on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM without any issues. The issue only occurs when I try to use a custom profile that I created using the autotailor command. Below is the error I ran into.

The reason for customizing the profile is there are some benchmarks that we need to exclude from the default Level 1 Server profile.

All commands I am using are from the OpenSCAP user manual (https://static.open-scap.org/openscap-1.3/oscap_user_manual.html#_creating_tailoring_files)

```
[root@localhost openscap]# oscap-ssh root@xx.x.x.xx 22 xccdf eval --remediate --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-custom --results ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-remediation-custom-results.xml --results-arf ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-arf-custom-results.xml ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-tailoring_1.xml
Connecting to 'root@xx.x.x.xx' on port '22'...
root@xx.x.x.xx's password: 
Connected!
Copying input file 'ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-tailoring_1.xml' to remote working directory '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj'...
ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2-tailoring_1.xml                                                                      100%  656     1.2MB/s   00:00    
Starting the evaluation...
OpenSCAP Error: Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unrecognized document type for: /tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:330]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Unable to open file: '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml' [../../../src/source/oscap_source.c:284]
Invalid (null) ((null)) content in /tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/file:///usr/share/openscap/ssg-ubuntu2204-ds-1.2.xml [../../../src/XCCDF/xccdf_session.c:628]
oscap exit code: 1
Copying back requested files...
File "/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/results.xml" not found.
Failed to download '/tmp/tmp.8KTqEvg4Pj/results.xml'
Failed to copy the results file back to local machine!
[root@localhost openscap]#
```

The end goal is to be able to use a custom CIS Level 1 Server profile to both evaluate and remediate an Ubuntu 22.04 VM remotely through a RHEL 9.2 VM. Any help with this issue is appreciated.